# How to convert boolean value which returned by function in select

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a next query, which doesn't work:

```
SELECT case BasePak.SomeFunction(333,4,5555) when true then 1 else 0 end 
               from dual
```

BasePak.SomeFunction(333,4,5555) returns boolean value. How to convert result(true, false) to number or string?

I tried cast function but not successful.

Is there any way to convert boolean to int or string?

Comment: What string do you want to convert to?

Comment: something like 
SELECT case BasePak.SomeFunction(333,4,5555) when 1 then "1" else "0" end from dual

Comment: If you use double quotes then it's an identifier @Arnab, i.e. a table/column etc. Use single quotes for strings, though these are numbers so there's no point having quotes at all.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have boolean datatype, but PL/SQL does. In PL/SQL you have more options. You can:

- write functions so they don't return boolean, but the type you need.
- if you can't edit the functions, you can write a wrapper function, that does the conversion
- or you can directly use code like this:

  ```
  string_var := CASE
  WHEN  boolean_var
  THEN  'True'
  WHEN  NOT boolean_var  -- or ELSE, depending on what you want
  THEN  'False'
  END;
  ```

In your case, I would either change the original function or write a wrapper function and use it directly from SQL code.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know SQL doesn't contain a Boolean datatype. A Bit is generally used to represent true (1) or false (0). Are you sure your function is not returning a NULL value as this needs to be handled differently

Try this instead:

```
SELECT case when BasePak.SomeFunction(333,4,5555) = 1 then 'true' else 'False' end 
from dual
```

Comment: If the function already returns a number then there's no need for the CASE statement...

Comment: Your suggestion isn't significantly different than the original sample query posted, which the author said did NOT work.